# Strange rule when voting to close as duplicate

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but I've never seen any other SE site require that the the question I'm calling a target of a duplicate question must have an upvoted or accepted answer. Is this just a Code Review thing? If it's not a bug, what's the rationale behind this rule?

[image]

I solved this by going to the other question, upvoting the answer that was there, and then marking this question as duplicate. I probably should have un-upvoted so others here could have the opportunity to reproduce it, but now my vote's locked.

Here's the question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27039/refactoring-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a change across the stack-exchange network

[Changes to "close as duplicate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate)

The rule doesn't make sense here, but we can't do much about it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the link. I can't say I agree with this rule, but the discussion is enlightening. I suppose it's just luck that I hadn't encountered this before.

Comment: Feel free to flag such duplicates (with an explanatory message!) so that they can be taken care of.